# Trying to find perfect number between two given values in c# using nested loop

Tags: c#, perfect-numbers

I am trying to find a perfect number between two given numbers for example 1 and 50. Unfortunately my code prints 1 and 24 as perfect numbers.

Can someone please correct this code and explain what they have done?

I am new to coding so please don't tell me about lists and stuff, I am here to seek your help to know where I am going wrong and how I can improve it. I shall be grateful to you if you will correct this code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int n3 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        //int sum;            

        for (int i = n2; i < n3; i++)
        {
            int sum = 0;

            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            {
                if (i % j == 0 )
                    sum = sum + j;

                //Console.WriteLine(j);
                if (sum == i )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("the sum is " + i);
                }
            }                                                            
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }                                           
}
```

Comment: Before we can help, you need to **define** what you mean by a "perfect number".  Explain to us, in plain English, what the code is supposed to accomplish.  What is the expected output?  Why are 1 and 24 not correct answers?

Comment: And if you are coming here for help on your code, you should listen to suggestions whether they include lists or dictionaries.

Comment: What is the definition of the perfect number?

Answer (score 2):

You need to begin by defining what a perfect number is. A perfect number is a positive integer that is **equal to the sum of its positive divisors**, **excluding the number itself**. Let examine your code

```
for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
```

According to your inner loop, you are NOT excluding the number itself. This needs to be changed to

```
for (int j = 1; j < i; j++).
```

The second issue with the code is that you are validating the sum way too early.

```
if (sum == i )
{
    Console.WriteLine("the sum is " + i);
}
```

The sum, at this point, could include only a part of positive divisors. You are yet to look though the entire list of divisors yet. So the validation part has to lie outside the inner loop. For example,

```
int n2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int n3 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

for (int i = n2; i < n3; i++)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int j = 1; j < i; j++)  // you need to exclude the number itself. So use Loop condition j <i, instead of j <=i
    {
        if (i % j == 0 )
        {
            sum = sum + j;

        }
    }      
    if (sum == i )  // Validate the sum with the number only after calculating sum of all divisors.
                {
        Console.WriteLine("the sum is " + i);
    }
}
```